# Changing backgroung color on mouse over using css

Tags: html, css

I am making a navigation menu. (http://jsfiddle.net/genxcoders/ZLh3F/)
css code is:

```
/* Menu */
        .menu {
            height: 100px;
            float: right;
            z-index: 100;
        }

        .menu li {
            display: inline;

        }

        .menu ul {
            margin-top: 45px;
        }

        .menu a {
            text-decoration : none;
            font-size: 15px;
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        .menu li a {

        }

        .menu a:hover {
            background-color: #306;
        }

        .active , .inactive {
            width: 800px;
            padding-left: 30px;
            padding-right: 30px;
            padding-top: 50px;
            padding-bottom: 34px;
        }

        .active {
            background-color: #306;
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        .inactive {
            color: #ffffff;
            background-color: #0CF;
        }
```

and HTML code is:

```
<div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="inactive"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li class="inactive"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li class="inactive"><a href="#">Product Support</a></li>
                    <li class="inactive"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li class="inactive"><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

I dont want the white gap in between but dont know how to do. Also, when i do a mouse over i want to achieve that the color should be the dark #306. i am able to only change the background-color of the text but then i want to achieve a tab kind of effect.

any help is appreciated. I am new to the field of development and i am still learning CSS.

I have also attached a JSFiddle link on the top. to show what i have done till now. the link is [here]:(http://jsfiddle.net/genxcoders/ZLh3F/)

Comment: Thanks a Lot to all of you for your help. I have got the menu going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
.menu a:hover {
    background-color: #306;
}
```

by

```
.menu li:hover {
    background-color: #306;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**EDIT:** for the entire block to be clickable juste put your `<li>` inside `<a>` like:

```
<a href="#"><li class="active">Home</li></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

give :hover to `<li>` not to `<a>`

Comment: it worked. wow... thanks... i also want the menus to be joint not the white space. how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
.menu li:hover {
       background-color: #306;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLh3F/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLh3F/7/

```
.menu {
    height: 100px;
    float: right;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 600px;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #0CF;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #306
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to

```
.menu li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

in this manner all the list elements will come close to each other because they adjust their width automatically

demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/aelor/ZLh3F/9/

as an alternative you can use `display:block` and `float:left` on the `li`s to remove the space. When they're inline the browser treats them as words, and so leaves space in between.

Comment: when i take my mouse over to the text i get to see the hand icon for clicking, is it possible to to make it like the entire box has the link that can be clicked?

Comment: @user3152887, check my answer below, for the link to be clicked.

Comment: @KingKing: but still it is not clickable. I can only click on the text to navigate. can we make the entire area clickable?

Comment: @user3152887 check this out , full li clickable : http://jsfiddle.net/aelor/ZLh3F/10/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the active and inactive classes to the `a` tag:

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="inactive">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="inactive">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="inactive">Product Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="inactive">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="inactive">FAQ</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In this way, the link area will be the full block, not only the text. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6ZM6z/4/

And in the `.menu li` style, add `float:left;width:auto;`:

```
.menu li {
  display: inline;
  float:left;
  width:auto;
}
```

**EDIT:** Updated example. I have not too much experience with JSFiddle :S